# One-to-one problem

Tags: functions

Prove that there isn't exist an one-to-one function

$ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $

with the property that $ f(x^3)+f(x)=x^2 $

If you can , the algebraic solution please

I've tried something like this : $ f(x)=x^2-f(x^3) $ but it is some recursion here

What's your opinion?

Comment: Consider $x=1,-1$...

Comment: Your suspicions should have been aroused by the "there is some recursion here". Is there a way to stop the recursion happening? Answer: yes, if you pick $x$ such that $x=x^3$.

Comment: @Macavity Explain why

Comment: You have an explanation from @PatrickStevens. You need to think through why the cases for $x$ I suggested will prevent a 1-1 map.

Answer (score 2):

Let's show that a function $f$ such that $f(x^3)+f(x)=x^2$ is not bijective.
What happens if we consider a point $x_0$ such that $x_0=x_0^3$ (i.e. $1$ or $-1$)?

If $x_0=1$, then

$$f(1)+f(1)=2f(1)=1^2 \implies f(1)=\frac 12$$

Consider $x_0=-1$:

$$f(-1)+f(-1)=2f(-1)=(-1)^2 \implies f(-1)=\frac 12$$

Since $f(1)=f(-1)$ the function is clearly not injective, so it cannot be one to one.